# How do I resolve "xml missing" with Rvest?

Tags: r, rvest, rselenium

This is the web page where I'm trying to get the information I need:
https://www.immobiliare.it/ricerca-mappa/Torino,TO/#/linkZona_/latitudine_45.04463/longitudine_7.68199/idContratto_1/idCategoria_23/zoom_16/pag_1

and this is the XPath associated to the node I'm intreseted:

```
//*[@id="box-listing"]/div[1]
```

While using

```
out %>%html_node(xpath = '//*[@id="box-listing"]/div[1]')
```

I ge the following error

```
{xml_missing}
<NA>
```

Comment: I am not sure about `html_node`  but many scraping tools do not support https. If you just have the one page,  try saving it from a browser and then read your local copy.

Comment: Thanks, after some research I belive it's due to dynamically updating the page. I'm looking on Selenium package and try to fiugre out how to use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem I suggest you to use `Rselinium`

We have two big families of web sites. The static web site and the dynamic web site.
The first one has the infomation that we need inside the code (for example Wikipidia web page), instead the second one doesn't have actually the information inside the code, but it makes it through the Javascript code every time we need it (for example Trip Advisor).
Thanks to `Rselenium` library we are able to scrape information from a dynamic web site.
What is Selenium?
`RSelenium` is a R library, but we can find it in `Python`, `Java` and so in other types of code and it is able to emulate the human behaviour.
The principal use of `Selenium` is to test the application automatization, but is not that case.

**Selenium is a very big world ( [here to deep](https://www.selenium.dev/)).**

About Rselenium I suggest you to check these links:

[GitHub repository](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium)

[Presentation](http://johndharrison.github.io/RSOCRUG/#1)

Below a small example using Rselenium about your question:

```
    library(RSelenium)
    
    #We start the RSelenium environment
    driver <- rsDriver(browser=c("firefox"),port = 4445L)
    remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]  
    
    #We send the url to the firefox browser
    remote_driver$navigate("https://www.immobiliare.it/ricerca-mappa/Torino,TO/#/linkZona_/latitudine_45.04462/longitudine_7.68199/idContratto_1/idCategoria_23/zoom_16/pag_1")
    
    Below some example of the Rselenium powerful
    
    #We get the text
    text_1<-remote_driver$findElement(using = "css selector", '#box-listing > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)')$getElementText()
    print(text_1)
    [[1]]
    [1] "PREMIUM\nImmobile\n€ 150.000\n60 m² • 2 locali"

    #We click the element
    remote_driver$findElement(using = "css selector", '#box-listing > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)')$clickElement()
```